# All files lost during long shelf time

Tags: pi-3, power, memory

i was using my raspberry pi 3 over ssh and doing a bunch of scripts, cron jobs, etc. then i stopped for a bit and shifted my focus elsewhere and my pi remained unplugged on my desk for a few months. under the impression that everything was saved to the sd card, i expected to boot it up and be right back where i left off, but no. all my files are gone. the music, the code, the pictures(the red flag was that my desktop bg wasnt a gpio map for the pi3, but a defaulted image of a road). the only thing that remains leaving proof that i was ever using it is the ssh password which i changed from the default 'raspberry'. is this a thing? i could understand things like old desktops doing this, which had a battery in them to keep it on(the core essentials like clock) while you changed houses, but i thought the pi was designed to be flash memory based and persistent even in lieu of power... is this normally expected behavior or a freak incident?

Comment: `the only thing that remains leaving proof that i was ever using it is the ssh password` - so, it's the right SD card - everything else a mystery only you can solve

Comment: its all gone. just a blank rpi after you set up the initial settings. thats what i need help figuring out about. i have a rpi2 that was right beside it, and used around the same time, but has all its info still on it. it actually has data from further back before the rpi3 was released on it, still in tact

Comment: sd cards don't revert to some previous state by being left on a shelf - you probably didn't make the changes you thought you did several months ago - the fact that the ssh password is not the default shows that the sd card is writable, so there's no issues there

Comment: `i could understand things like old desktops doing this, which had a battery in them to keep it on(the core essentials like clock) while you changed houses` even this isn't a thing ... the battery in PC's is merely to keep the BIOS settings intact in NVRAM - content of filesystem is not reliant on any form of power in either a PC or raspberry pi

Comment: Like Jaromanda said, you or someone else did something else that caused the situation. Shelf time didn't do it. The SD card you had your previous files on was either replaced with a different one or it was wiped and replaced with a new raspbian image that the only thing you did to it was to reset the password.

Comment: Was all your code in the home directory? Settings for background would also be there,  so maybe the home directory got deleted?

Comment: All I can say is.. that the SD card is some kind of fake. I see this a lot with SD cards and its infuriating.Even during normal usage fake SD cards just blow up (stop working) beyond any way of fixing them again. I now only buy samsung or kingston SD cards from big wholesalers - but I read in the news recently even they where being supplied fakes "without their knowledge" - but I paid a bit more for these and have had cards lying around for 12 months+ with no issues now and they operate fast and reliably all the time

Comment: Not specifically Pi, but Linux allows configuring ramdisk or tmpfs filesystems.  These do not have persistence, but can be confused for filesystems on the SD.  Also, "live" methods read from a read-only filesystem and cache writes, so that the read-only filesystem appears to be writable.  Again, changes are not persistent across boots.  Look at /proc/mounts for information about currently mounted filesystems.